# When Java applications are launched a cmd screen flashes and does nothing

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java

I tried to open a java application, it's called [mcpatcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=46173). It flashed a cmd screen and the application didn't open?

This might belong in the gaming section but I think it is more related to computers because every other java application I tried didn't work. I set PATH and everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it right from cmd window, maybe you'll get some error messages that could help to find where the problem is